# After XResizeWindow, new window content drawn is not displayed

Tags: linux, resize, window, cairo, xlib

I'm writing an application in Linux using **Xlib** to manage a window and **cairo** to draw some text in it. The text content of the window changes during the execution, so I want to adapt the window size to match that of the text extent. If the size of the text extent does not change, the window is always correctly updated with the new text.

But when the text extent changes, and so the window is resized accordingly, the window is cleared but the new text is never shown. Only if there is no call to XResizeWindow the text is actually displayed. The code I'm using is

```c
if (/* Text extent is changed */)
{
    XResizeWindow (display, window, new_width, new_height);
    cairo_xlib_surface_set_size (surface, new_width, new_height);
}

XClearWindow (display, window);

/* ... Cairo code to draw the text ... */

// cairo_surface_flush (surface);
// XFlush (display);
```

I have also tried to add after the Cairo code that draws the text the methods **cairo_surface_flush** and **XFlush** (commented in the example) but nothing changes.

**EDIT:** I solved the problem using **two threads**: the first thread with the usual loop for listening to the Expose events plus the code to redraw the content and the second thread that issues the resize of the window and sends an Expose event to wake up the first thread.

In this example the window is resized every 500 ms to random width and height and a progressive counter is displayed in it at every resize. I use C++11, compile with:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o test test.cpp -lX11 -lcairo -lpthread
```

The code is:

```c
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <cairo/cairo-xlib.h>

Display * d;
Window w;
cairo_surface_t * surface;
int width = 300, height = 300;
unsigned char counter = 0;
std::random_device rd;
std::knuth_b gen (rd ());
std::uniform_int_distribution < > dist (150, 300);

void logic ()
{
    XEvent send_event;
    send_event.type = Expose;
    send_event.xexpose.window = w;
        
    while (true)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::milliseconds (500));
        ++ counter;
        width = dist (gen);
        height = dist (gen);
        cairo_xlib_surface_set_size (surface, width, height);
        XResizeWindow (d, w, width, height);
        XSendEvent (d, w, False, ExposureMask, & send_event);
        XFlush (d);
    }
}

int main ( )
{
    XInitThreads ();

    d = XOpenDisplay (NULL);
    w = XCreateSimpleWindow (d, RootWindow (d, 0), 0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, 0x000000);
    XMapWindow (d, w);
    XSelectInput (d, w, ExposureMask | KeyPressMask);

    surface = cairo_xlib_surface_create (d, w, DefaultVisual (d, 0), width, height);
    cairo_t * cairo = cairo_create (surface);
    cairo_select_font_face (cairo, "FreeSans", CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_NORMAL, CAIRO_FONT_WEIGHT_BOLD);
    cairo_set_font_size (cairo, 40 );
    cairo_set_source_rgb (cairo, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8);
    cairo_move_to (cairo, 40.0, 60.0);
    cairo_show_text (cairo, std::to_string (counter).c_str ());
    XFlush (d);
    
    std::thread T (logic);

    XEvent event;
    while (true)
    {
        XNextEvent (d, & event);
        if (event.type == Expose)
        {
            XClearWindow (d, w);
            cairo_move_to (cairo, 40.0, 60.0);
            cairo_show_text (cairo, std::to_string (counter).c_str ());
        }
        else if (event.type == KeyPress)
        {
            XCloseDisplay (d);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

*But a question remains*: is it possible to obtain the same result using only **one thread**?

Comment: Do you have a self-contained example that one could test? How does your event-loop look like, i.e. what do you do on Expose events?

Comment: Ok I will provide a compact self-contained code example that reproduces the behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a single-threaded version of your code. It is not nice, but it seems to work. The hard part is waiting for events from the X11 server and the timeout simultaneously. I do this with `select()` in the following code.
Note that I also handle `ConfigureNotify` events instead of assuming that `XResizeWindow` always does just what we want.

```c
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <cairo/cairo-xlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

Display * d;
Window w;
cairo_surface_t * surface;
int width = 300, height = 300;
unsigned char counter = 0;
std::random_device rd;
std::knuth_b gen (rd ());
std::uniform_int_distribution < > dist (150, 300);

void do_update ()
{
        ++ counter;
        width = dist (gen);
        height = dist (gen);
        XResizeWindow (d, w, width, height);
        // Force a redraw
        XClearArea(d, w, 0, 0, 0, 0, True);
}

int main ( )
{
    XInitThreads ();

    d = XOpenDisplay (NULL);
    w = XCreateSimpleWindow (d, RootWindow (d, 0), 0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, 0x000000);
    XMapWindow (d, w);
    XSelectInput (d, w, ExposureMask | KeyPressMask);

    surface = cairo_xlib_surface_create (d, w, DefaultVisual (d, 0), width, height);
    cairo_t * cairo = cairo_create (surface);
    cairo_select_font_face (cairo, "FreeSans", CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_NORMAL, CAIRO_FONT_WEIGHT_BOLD);
    cairo_set_font_size (cairo, 40 );
    cairo_set_source_rgb (cairo, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8);
    cairo_move_to (cairo, 40.0, 60.0);
    cairo_show_text (cairo, std::to_string (counter).c_str ());
    XFlush (d);

    struct timeval next_update;
    struct timeval now;
    struct timeval interval = { 0, 500000 };
    gettimeofday(&now, NULL);
    timeradd(&now, &interval, &next_update);

    while (true)
    {
        XEvent event;

        gettimeofday(&now, NULL);
        if (timercmp(&now, &next_update, >)) {
            // Store time of next update
            timeradd(&now, &interval, &next_update);
            puts("update");
            do_update();
        }

        if (!XPending(d)) {
            struct timeval remaining;
            fd_set fds;
            int fd = ConnectionNumber(d);
            FD_ZERO(&fds);
            FD_SET(fd, &fds);
            timersub(&next_update, &now, &remaining);
            select(fd + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &remaining);
        } else {
            XNextEvent (d, & event);
            if (event.type == Expose)
            {
                XClearWindow (d, w);
                cairo_move_to (cairo, 40.0, 60.0);
                cairo_show_text (cairo, std::to_string (counter).c_str ());
            }
            if (event.type == ConfigureNotify)
            {
                cairo_xlib_surface_set_size (surface, event.xconfigure.width, event.xconfigure.height);
            }
            else if (event.type == KeyPress)
            {
                XCloseDisplay (d);
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is quite interesting, thanks. A couple of question: 1) Is the **select** function used just to wait and implement the timer or there is also something related to waiting for non blocking reads on the file descriptor of the display? 2) Is the ClearArea function used in update () used just to trigger the sending of an Expose event from the server?

Comment: 1) Well... select() is used for "wait until time elapsed, but handle all events from the server immediately, if any arrive". 2) Yup. 3) Note that I did not optimize this code in any way. It has to call cairo_surface_flush() after drawing. It should only handle expose events whose count entry is zero etc. Likely lots of other problems.

Comment: Ok, got it... But still a doubt remains for me about the working of the X server, and it's in fact at the origin of my question. I don't understand why, even after the client calls XFlush or XSync, the server doesn't perform the actual drawing on the window. It seems that only if the client is reading in the usual loop the Expose events with XNextEvent, the server will actually honor the client drawing requests. Why is this? Is the server checking if the client has read the Expose event, and then perform the actual drawing?

Comment: I can only guess. Here is my guess: You original code resized the window and immediately drew the new content. However, you cannot just resize your own windows. Instead, this turns into a request to the window manager "please resize this window" (and the window manager is free to ignore this request or choose a different size!). So what happens is: You request a resize to the window; you redraw the window while it still has the old size; only afterwards does the window manager actually resize the window

Comment: In fact I did not considered the window manager in the equation in this particular case. My idea was that the window manager intervenes when there is an action from the user like using the mouse, clicking and dragging the border of a window. It then translates these events in proper requests to the X server for that window. But not when a client application itself is sending directly requests to the server from its code. Do you mean that the window manager is able to intercept and manipulating them? How can it do this? And why should?

Comment: How: Select the SubstructureRedirect event on a window. A ConfigureWindow request (which is what XResizeWindow uses internally) is then turned into a ConfigureRequest event and sent to the WM (and otherwise ignored by the server). The WM can still send ConfigureWindow requests without being redirect. Why: The WM takes your window and places it in another window of its own. In this window it draws e.g. the titlebar (close button, ...). When "your" window is resized, the window created by the WM also needs to be resized.

Comment: Random Google result: https://seasonofcode.com/posts/how-x-window-managers-work-and-how-to-write-one-part-i.html#substructure-redirection